# MVC how to pass both value and text of dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Good day. I know that when a `dropdownlist` is selected, the value is the one is that being passed. What I would like to know is whether it is possible to pass also the `Text`?

I have created a system wherein the user selects from a `dropdownlist` and when button is clicked, a preview should pop-up.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.CStatuss = new SelectList(db.CStatus, "id", "status");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CivilStatus, (SelectList)ViewBag.CStatuss, "Choose a Status", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cstatus" })
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
        $('#Tacstatus').text($('#cstatus').val());
});
```

**Preview**

```
<table class="table">
     <tr>
         <th>Civil Status</th>
        <td id="Tacstatus"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that I want the preview to show the `Text` based on the selected item in the dropdownlist. I could simply change the `val` being called but I would have a problem with my database since the needed value here is the `val` itself and not the `text`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('#Tacstatus').text($('#cstatus').find('option:selected').text());`

Comment: `$('#cstatus option:selected').text()` should get it I think, from memory. Pretty sure this will have been asked before it you search (maybe not specific to MVC, but it doesn't need to be - it doesn't matter what you use to create the dropdown, jQuery just works on the resulting HTML)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Tried your code and it worked! Thanks